# In bash, how can I search and replace over multiple lines in a yaml file?

Tags: bash, shell, replace, yaml

I’m using bash shell.  I have a series of YAML files formatted like so

```
qa:
  property1: abcdef
  property2: xyzhijkl
  …

production:
```

I would like to write a script to copy everything between the “qa” and “production” blocks to put the properties under "qa" into an additional "qa2" block.  The above would be converted to

```
qa:
  property1: abcdef
  property2: xyzhijkl
  …

qa2:
  property1: abcdef
  property2: xyzhijkl
  …

production:
```

Is there a way I could write a bash script to do the search and replacement?

Comment: Not a direct answer to your question, but I would recommend seeing if yaml anchors solves what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trivial solution using [yq](https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/):

```
yq e '.qa2 = .qa' test.yaml
```

This will put `qa2` after production, which shouldn't matter because that has the exact same semantics according to the YAML spec. If you still dislike it, put it before `production` by removing that and adding it back later:

```
yq e '.production as $p | del(.production) | .qa2 = .qa | .production = $p' test.yaml
```

Answer (score 0):

If `sed` is an option

```
$ sed -n '/^qa/,/^$/{P;s/^qa/qa2/;H;d};x;p;' input_file
qa:
  property1: abcdef
  property2: xyzhijkl
  …


qa2:
  property1: abcdef
  property2: xyzhijkl
  …

production:
```

Comment: FYI, when i tried your solution on a bash shell on Mac, I got the error, "sed: 1: "/^qa/,/^$/{P;s/^qa/qa2/ ...": extra characters at the end of d command"